# Non-Borel subspace of Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reference-request

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space, $M \subset X$ a linear subspace.  Must $M$ be a Borel set in $X$?

I believe the answer is "no," since I have seen authors who are careful to talk about "Borel subspaces".  But I have not been able to find a counterexample.

If the answer is indeed "no", does every infinite-dimensional separable Banach space contain a non-Borel dense linear subspace?

Comment: Wild guess: suppose $X$ is infinite dimensional, pick a Hamel basis of $X$, and let $M$ be the span of a proper infinite subset of that basis.  Then I'm guessing $M$ will not be Borel.

Comment: What about the kernel of a non-continuous linear functional?

Comment: @Mark: any infinite-dimensional subspace $M$ of $X$ is the span of an infinite subspace of a Hamel basis for $X$.  (Take a Hamel basis for $M$ and use Zorn to extend it to a Hamel basis for $X$.)  So any subspace can be produced by your construction, including, say, the closed ones, so it need not produce a non-Borel subspace.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say cofinite.  

Comment: But from Bill's comments on Gerald's answer, it looks like even what I meant to write may not be right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an answer, but not the "right" answer".

Presumably you mean that $X$ is infinite dimensional and hence has Hamel dimension the continuum $c$.  For every subset of a given Hamel basis you get the linear subspace spanned by the subset, and these subspaces are different for different subsets of the basis.  Thus $X$ has $2^c$ linear subspaces but only $c$ Borel sets (since $X$ is separable).

EDIT: I just noticed the second question.  Consider subsets of the basis that all contain one fixed countable subset whose span is dense.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was discussed before and answered (in particular to Bill's question in the comments)

[Are proper linear subspaces of Banach spaces always meager?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3188/are-proper-linear-subspaces-of-banach-spaces-always-meager)

Comment: Yes; that gives the "right" answer to Nate's question.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that question, but failed to unwind it far enough to see that it addressed my question as well.  Now I see it.

Answer (score -1):

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space.  Any linear subspace with the property of Baire (in particular, any linear subspace that is a Borel set) is closed.  According to the Axiom of Choice, if $X$ is also infinite-dimensional, then there are discontinuous linear functionals, and their kernels are non-closed (and hence non-Borel) linear subspaces---of course these are dense.

**EDIT**
The above is clearly wrong, as the comments show.  I could try to salvage something maybe saying $G_\delta$-set instead of property of Baire, but that would not answer the original question here.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Perhaps I myself am dense (pun intended), but I don't see why a Borel subspace must have the Baire property, nor why a subspace with the Baire property must be closed.

Comment: Gerry, $\ell_2$ is $F_\sigma$ in $\ell_4$ but not closed, which contradicts part of what you wrote.

Comment: So the question remains for the infinite dimensional space $X$:

1. Is every dense codimension one subspace of $X$ Borel?

2. Does there exist a dense codimension one subspace of $X$ that is Borel?

(Exercise: Show, for a fixed $X$, that this really is just one question.)



Comment: And the answer should be: A non-closed hyperplane (in a separable Banach space) must be non-Borel.  Intuitively, non-closed hyperplanes live way out in Axiom-Of-Choice land, but Borel sets don't... But that's not a proof.

