# Convergence of functionals on compact projections on a separable Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$, say $\ell_2$ for simplicity. Let $\mathcal{K}(H)$ denote the space of all compact operators on $H$ and $\mathcal{P}(H)$ the set of all finite rank orthogonal projections on $H$ (so $\mathcal{P}(H)\subset\mathcal{K}(H)$). Assume that $(x_n^*)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of bounded functionals on $\mathcal{K}(H)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^*(P)=0$ for every $P\in\mathcal{P}(H)$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^*(T)=0$ for every $T\in\mathcal{K}(H)$?

Equivalently, is $(x_n^*)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ norm bounded? Such a situation holds e.g. in von Neumann algebras (a result due to Darst '67) or C*-algebras of the form $C(K)$ where $K$ is the Stone space of a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra (Nikodym '33).

**References:**

R.B. Darst, *On a theorem of Nikodym with applications to weak convergence
and von Neumann algebras*, Pacific J. Math. 23 (1967), no. 3, 473–477.

O. Nikodym, *Sur les familles bornées de fonctions parfaitement additives
d’ensemble abstrait*, Monatsh. Math. Phys. 40 (1933), no. 1, 418–426.

Comment: Why *compact projections*? This is a confusing way of writing projections onto finite-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: [deleted previous comment; I missed the fact that we are not assuming $\sup_n \Vert x_n^*\Vert < \infty$ ]

Comment: @DavidHandelman: I just mean only the projections which belong to $\mathcal{K}(H)$.

Comment: But aren't those precisely the projections whose images are finite dimensional?

Comment: @NateEldredge: why do you think this is equivalent? Finite rank operators are just dense in $\mathcal{K}(H)$, so you need to take the closure to obtain entire $\mathcal{K}(H)$. Hence, actually, this is the same problem as going from finite rank projections to all compact operators. Or I miss something?

Comment: And yes, the compact projections are precisely those which are finite rank.

Comment: Does "projection" here mean *orthogonal* projection?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, of course! I meant orthogonal projections. I have edited the post.

Comment: @NateEldredge: every element of a C*-algebra is a linear combination of two self-adjoint elements, so the set of self-adjoint operators is not a subspace (or, it is, but over $\mathbb{R}$, but I am concerned with the complex case). Hence, what you say is wrong. And in the case of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, every operator is compact, so $\mathcal{K}(H)=\mathcal{B}(H)$ satisfies the demanded condition, since it is a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Oh, we are over $\mathbb{C}$.  Ok, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ok, let me try again with my comment from yesterday.  If the answer to your question is **yes**, then the answer to my (currently unresolved) Q2 [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148691/meager-subspaces-of-a-banach-space-and-weak-convergence) is **no**.  Let $X = \mathcal{K}(H)$ and let $E \subset X$ be the space of finite rank operators.  Let $\{x_n^*\} \subset X^*$ be a sequence of bounded functionals, and suppose $x_n^*(T) \to 0$ for all $T \in E$.  In particular, $x_n^*(P) \to 0$ for all compact projections $P$ (since they have finite rank). (cont'd)

Comment: If the answer to your question is yes, then we may conclude that $x_n^*(T) \to 0$ for every $T \in X$.  Since $\{x_n^*\}$ was arbitrary, in the terminology of my question, we have that $E$ determines weak-* convergence.  Yet $E$ is meager in $X$, since the set $E_n$ of operators having rank at most $n$ is closed and nowhere dense, and $E = \bigcup_n E_n$.  My question Q2 was whether a subspace determines weak-* convergence iff it is nonmeager, so the answer to Q2 would be **no**.

Comment: As such, I will be very happy if the answer to your question is **yes**, but I am more inclined to suspect it will turn out to be **no**.

Comment: Would you be able to give the full citations to the papers of Darst and Nikodym?  I am wondering if they might be relevant to my other question.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Done. In fact, concerning your problem Q2 the literature is quite vast, I think. I'll contact you later via mail (at unco.edu).

Answer (score 3):

This is false. The dual $K(H)^*=B_1(H)$ is given by the trace class operators, and an $S\in B_1(H)$ acts on a $T\in K(H)$ by $(S,T)=\textrm{tr}\, ST$. Consider now
$$
S_n = n2^{-n} \sum_{2^n\le j<2^{n+1}} \langle e_j , \cdot \rangle e_j .
$$
The norm of $S_n$ as a functional is its trace norm, which equals $n$, so this sequence is unbounded. However, your condition holds: it suffices to check this for a rank one projection $T=\langle v, \cdot \rangle v$, and then
$$
(S_n,T) = n2^{-n}\sum |\langle e_j, v\rangle |^2 \le n2^{-n}\to 0 ,
$$
as required.